# Rails view with association within an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple form and decent exposure - I have a view for a Visit - A household makes the visit and each household has 1 or more neighbors or household members. I have tried this:

```
= simple_form_for visit do |f|
  = f.association :household, :label => 'Household',prompt:'choose a household'
  - household.neighbors.each do |neighbor|
    %tr
      %td= link_to neighbor.name, neighbor_path(neighbor)
      %td= neighbor.age
      %td= neighbor.visits.count
```

I can choose a Household with the association but I am having difficulty showing the neighbors that belong to the household - what I have above works in the household view but it doesn't work here  - I need to return the household from the association to make it available for the neighbor lookup

How do I do this?

My Controller:

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:visit)
  expose(:visits)
  helper_method :visit, :visits

def create
  if visit.save
    redirect_to visits_path, notice: 'Visit was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

def update
  if visit.save
    redirect_to visits_path, notice: 'Visit was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

def destroy
  visit.destroy

  redirect_to visits_path
end

private

def allowable
  [
    :household_id, :neighbor_id, :visited_on, :items_received, :notes
  ]
end

  def visit_params
   params.require(:visit).permit(*allowable)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your models and controller code for the action?

Comment: To load the neighbors dynamically you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: I put in the controller - last night I realized I should just have a view tied to my household model that show the associated neighbors and visits then to add a new visit use something like cocoon